# Prevent PHP from sending the PHPSESSID cookie with requests?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am serving dynamic image content which is generated by PHP. But for such requests to a .php file, the PHPSESSID cookie is being sent along, which is a waste.

Is it possible to prevent PHP from sending this cookie with requests to a PHP file? Or is it completely necessary for PHP to work?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. When you use session_start() in a php script, the browser is given a session cookie. As long as the browser has that cookie, the browser will send it with each request.

Comment: @Rob: He's basically asking how to omit cookies when serving images by PHP (I realized that later as well and thus deleted my worthless answer). Matthew has it right, just use another domain/path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser will send any cookie that applies to a certain path-domain combination.  You have no control over that, except using different paths and domains.  This is why many sites use [static content domains](http://sstatic.net/).

Comment: Aahh.. I use static content domain for some stuff. Somehow failed to use my mind in this case. Anyway, thanks Mathew!

Answer (score 1):

This is used by PHP's session functions. If your site doesn't use sessions, then this probably shouldn't be showing up.

Keep in mind that the cookie is sent by the browser and you have no control over its transmission.

Answer (score 0):

you're saying "dont use cookies for sessions, use a phpsessid as a get parameter" php deprecated this for a reason.
Cookies will always be sent to the same domain.  If you really want to avoid the *MINIMAL* overhead, resources which dont need cookies should be in a separate domain, thus the cookie wont be sent. IE.  static.domain.com for static content.
It's not worth the hassle, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

i've searched and this is the only solution i found that worked for me.

Add the following code to your .htaccess file:

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$
>
> RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry, what is that doing exactly? It seems to strip all parameters from a request and redirect if the QUERY_STRING contains a session id.